# Who was the piano player that Starbuck met in the bar on Galactica?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-2004

Towards the end of season four, Starbuck meets a piano player in the makeshift bar on Galactica.

Now, it appears that this guy is some kind of ghost/angel like Caprica-6 and the ghost Baltar - but I have an idea that he could also be the original copy of the seventh model (Daniel). It's mentioned right in the episode before that Cavil poisoned all of the bodies that were being prepared to accept a copy of Daniel - but it's ambiguous about the fate of the original cylon with that personality. Daniel was also mentioned as an 'artist' and 'sensitive' person.

So - could it have been Daniel that helped Starbuck realise what the music meant?

Comment: This invites speculation, but it's possible the question could be  answered (even if the answer is that it's impossible to say).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The person she meets is a vision of her father, [Dreillide "Slick" Thrace](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Slick).

It's not Daniel, as RDM has specifically said [he's not a part of the series](http://en.battlestarwiki.org/wiki/Number_Seven) and was only important insofar as he was mentioned in passing as being Abel to Cavil's Cain.

Comment: Wouldn't Starbuck have recognised her own father? Thanks for the link though - it pretty much reveals everything that my question was asking :)

Comment: @HorusKol It's been a while since I saw the episode, but if I remember correctly, he left when she was just a child. This would allow for her to feel he was familiar, but not immediately recognize him as her father.

Comment: Meh, this is one of those plot threads I feel like they blew it with.  They left it with a perfect set up for the piano man to be Starbuck's father and for Starbuck's father to be Daniel.  And for that to somehow explain Starbuck's ressurection.  Which would have been infinitely more satisfying than with them having her simply disappear and it being left open.

Comment: @Daniel Seriously. There seemed to be a real plot hole around Starbucks resurrection which was never really adequately addressed.

Comment: @Nathan: How so? "God did it". Weak perhaps, but not a hole.

Comment: Remember this is post Starbucks return, she was no longer "normal" by any means, and she was being guided by many strange things. An angel in the form of her father was just one of them.

Comment: @HorusKol In addition to him leaving when she was still a child and so her memories of him being vague, I think there is another important explanation related to her father's *age*.  One might wonder, even if her direct memories of her father were fuzzy, wouldn't she have had some pictures of him?  We could guess that maybe her mother, bitter about being abandoned, had erased all traces of his existence, but I also think that her father was quite old when left - maybe 40 or 50.  In the show, there is a shot of him on his album cover with a long, straggly beard and he looks like he could be 70.

Comment: @HorusKol (cont.) So, even if Starbuck had memories of him from when she was younger, those memories would have been of a man 40+.  Even if she had pictures of him when he was younger (if her mom kept any), those pictures might also have been of an older man 40+.  Additionally, she might also have seen later pictures of him (as on the album cover) of a man around 60 or 70.  Either way, she wouldn't have an image in her mind of, nor an expectation of ever seeing, her father in real life as a much younger man of about 30.  That could easily explain why she didn't immediately recognize him.

Answer (score 0):

I've always held that it's God. Kara was abandoned by her "father" at a young age, and her mother raised her. Its a fracked up spin on Jesus.  God blesses girl with a child and leaves her to care for it.

Kara is an angel and our messiah, and the piano Man is her father and God guiding her just before she fulfills her destiny. That episode is in essence her night in the garden.

All this has happened before, and all this will happen again.

Comment: It's important to note here, for the sake of clarity and canon in this series, that she was not a messiah. The hybrid in "razor" foretold she was the harbinger of death. From all the foreshadowing and other cryptic messages put in the show, death can be interpreted in different ways. It could be the death of Rosalyn, death of life as they know it, death of galactica, it. Could also be change. Harbinger refers to someone who brings a message, which is why she would be leading the way, but being the bearer of a message of change/death in any form does not make her a messiah.

Comment: @BrandonZadel Eh, Jesus primarily brought a message.  A message of change and death.  The old law was dying.  The old Jewish system was dying.  Jesus himself was dying.  A new order was coming.  Like Moses, Jesus was there to point the way and guide his people into the "new land" (or new way of things), but would not actually be there (physically anyway) after they got there.  Granted, Laura was more of the Moses character, but there are too many parallels between Moses, Messiah, and Starbuck for you to so definitively dismiss the theory outright.

Comment: I've always had this idea in my own head canon as well.  I've posted it many times before but I'll just reference this recent reddit post where I fleshed it out in a little more detail: https://www.reddit.com/r/BSG/comments/9on4ko/bsg_thoughts_second_watch/e7vtp5b/

Comment: Here is a (rather in-depth) review of Daybreak that briefly compares Starbuck to Jesus as well: https://vicmackey187.livejournal.com/40132.html

Answer (score -1):

Here are some things to think about:

The Daniel model was not boxed, but corrupted and thus destroyed.  If I were writing the story, I would have it that Daniel was visiting the colonies and appreciated humans and all of their art and such.  When Jon (Brother Cavil) found out, he used it as an excuse to destroy the line.  Meanwhile he had fallen in love with and had a child with a human.

Kara's father was a piano player.  He left when she was young.  At the end of the song, he pointed his finger at her and she blew on it, just like her father did.

The song that she "remembered" him teaching her was the same that the 5 remembered from Earth 2,000 years before.  It is also the notes in the song that lead her to the new planet.  And it's also the song that Hera wrote when drawing stars.

Just my take on it all.